# Dojo building system for jQuery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The build system from Dojo can be used to bundle all the modules into a single file so that you get modularity during development and performance during deployment.  Is there such a system for jQuery or a general way of doing this in javascript(with no frameworks like Dojo)?

Comment: Are you looking for: http://requirejs.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dojo just implements the [Asynchronous Module Definition](http://www.requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#amd) (AMD) interface. It is supposed to be a common standard and you can find other implementations, like, for example, [requireJs](http://requirejs.org).